# Tableau- if statement with aggregation

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

I want to calculate the percentage of "class = high" per store
Thanks

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFFuD.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(int([class]=“high”)) / count([class])
```